# How to stream a list with a inner list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need some Help with streams in Java 8.
I have a name-list with an inner integer number-list like this code and example:

```
public class Test {

    private String name;    
    private List<Integer> nrList;    

    public Test() {
    }

    public Test(String name, List<Integer> nrList) {

        this.name = name;
        this.nrList = nrList;        
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Integer> getNrList() {
        return nrList;
    }
}
```

For example, I want this:

```
1. Alex 10 15
2. Steve 5
3. Bob 3 16 20
```

to stream into a redundant list of names like this:

```
1. Alex 10
2. Alex 15
3. Steve 5
4. Bob 3
5. Bob 16
6. Bob 20
```

How can I handle this with Java 8 streams?

Comment: Are you talking about List<Test> ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to generate a unique element for each element of the inner lists.

For example, if you want the output to be a `List<String>` where each `String` is a concatenation of a name and one of the corresponding integers :

```
List<Test> input = ...
List<String> output = input.stream()
                           .flatMap(t->t.getNrList().stream().map(i->t.getName() + " " + i))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course you can generate a `List` of any element type as output (for example, a `List<Test>` output where the inner list of each `Test` instance has just one element), depending on your requirements. Your just have to change the mapping function passed to `map` to generate the required instance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is:

```
    List<Test> lt = new ArrayList<>();
    lt.add(new Test("1", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
    lt.add(new Test("2", Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4)));

    List<Test> lt2 =
            lt.stream()
                    .map(test ->
                            test.getNrList().stream()
                                    .map(number -> new Test(test.getName(), Arrays.asList(number)))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```